# Preventing indentation on new line within enumitem's description command

Tags: lists, enumitem, description, noindent

I am using the enumitem package, and I am trying to prevent the indentation on a new line within an item command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\SetLabelAlign{margin}{\llap{#1~~}}

\lhead{\LARGE\textbf{Name}}
\rhead{Date}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[align=margin,labelsep=0pt]

\item[\normalfont Contact] Place A \hfill Place B \\ 
\noindent
Thing A \hfill Thing B

\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, `\noindent` does not work here. I would like "Place A" and "Thing A" to be aligned vertically. I could not find the solution in the documentation for enumitem, nor on here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you want is

```
\begin{description}[align=margin,leftmargin=0pt,labelsep=0pt,itemindent=0pt]
```

which generates

[image]

I assume the intention is for the entry name in the description list to protrude into the left margin. Beware of longer entry names: if you had "Telephone numbers" instead of "Contact" then the beginning of "Telephone" would float off the page. Better put the label into a `\parbox` then.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\SetLabelAlign{margin}{\llap{\parbox[t]{0.6in}{\raggedleft #1}~~}}

\lhead{\LARGE\textbf{Name}}
\rhead{Date}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[align=margin,leftmargin=0pt,labelsep=0pt,itemindent=0pt]
\item[\normalfont Contact] Place A \hfill Place B \\ 
Thing A \hfill Thing B
\item[\normalfont Telephone numbers] Number 1
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Incidentally, if you are confident you won't have very long entry names (labels), then a simpler version that does not require defining your own alignment is `\begin{description}[align=right,leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=0pt,labelsep=1em]`. This would force a negative `labelindent`.